# Integrating planning tools in wordpress

Tags: plugins, multisite, multisite-user-management

Is there a way in wordpress that can integrate planning tools e.g If I need to provide tools, for example a guest list manager or a budget calculator, how do I integrate an these along with  the site which will be linked to each user's account?

Is it through creating a multisite and assigning each registered user with a site and having the tools on the users site that can be accessed by the user only?

Any thought?

Comment: Could you possibly be a bit more specific as to what it is you'd like to achieve? Do you have the tools you speak of at hand or are they hypothetical constructs? For now, I'd call this question [*too broad*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @JohannesPille, thanks there are various plugins thats can do this. e.g a to-do list plugin, or any rsvp plugin. However these generally can not be linked to each user. I want way where i can link a to-do list to a user for example, where a user can save the do-do list on my list, come back later to login update the list. Similarly for other tools i want the same functionality where a user can login to make a guest list, save it, etc